# SwiftUI: Customizing the Native Navigation Bar in SwiftUI to Mimic the Apple TV App's Style and Animations - iOS 16

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios16, swiftui-navigationstack

How can I customize the native navigation bar in SwiftUI to resemble the one used in the Apple TV app for iOS? On the detail screen, there's a native navigation bar where the tint color of the toolbar button item and the navigation bar background change when scrolling.

I'm aware that I can replicate the same behavior by using a ZStack and a custom navigation bar, along with a GeometryReader to adjust the opacity. However, I'd like to achieve this using the native navigation bar and toolbar so that I can take advantage of all the built-in animations.

I've attempted to modify the color using `.toolbarBackground(.gray.opacity(0.5), for: .navigationBar)`, but even when the opacity is set to 0, the color isn't completely clear. Also, how can I animate the color change during scrolling?

[image: Detail screen with background image and white color Tool bar items with Blur circle background]

[image: Detail screen with white navigation bar when scroll down to content]

Comment: Have you tried creating your own custom toolbar, and then setting its background color to clear? Like, literally `.background(Color.clear)`?